# Vertical alignment in anchor with svg icon and text

Tags: css, svg, icons, anchor, vertical-alignment

```css
:root {
  --main-font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  --main-font-size: 14px;
  --main-line-height: 1.71;
  --logo-font-family: Raleway, Roboto, sans-serif;
  --logo-font-size: 26px;
  --main-letter-spacing: 0.03em;

  --main-font-color: #757575;
  --title-font-color: #212121;
  --logo-font-color: #000000;
  --main-light-color: #ffffff;
  --contacts-font-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  --accent-color: #2196f3;
  --main-dark-color: #2f303a;
  --secondary-bg-color: #f5f4fa;
  --header-border-color: #ececec;
}

/* Загальні стилі */

body.studio {
  font-family: var(--main-font-family);
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
  line-height: var(--main-line-height);
  letter-spacing: var(--main-letter-spacing);

  color: var(--main-font-color);
  background-color: var(--main-light-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

main img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

/* .container.big-container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding: 0;
} */

.section {
  padding-top: 94px;
  padding-bottom: 94px;
}

.title {
  color: var(--title-font-color);
}

.header .nav-link,
.header .nav-contact,
.footer .address-geo,
.footer .address-contact {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .nav-list,
.header .nav-contacts,
.footer .address-list,
.benefits-list,
.doing-list,
.team-list,
.works-list,
.works-filters {
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
  font-family: var(--logo-font-family);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: var(--logo-font-size);
  line-height: 1.174;
  letter-spacing: var(--main-letter-spacing);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accent {
  color: var(--accent-color);
}

.unvisible {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
}

/* Шапка */

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--header-border-color);
}

.header .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav.flex-container {
  column-gap: 93px;
}

.header .logo {
  color: var(--logo-font-color);
}

.header .nav-list {
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.nav-item {
  line-height: 0;
}

.header .nav-link,
.header .nav-contact {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.17;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}

.header .nav-link {
  display: block;

  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 31px;

  color: var(--title-font-color);
}

.header .nav-contacts {
  margin-left: auto;

  column-gap: 50px;
}

.header .nav-contact {
  color: inherit;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  fill: var(--main-font-color);
}

.icon-envelope {
  width: 16px;
  height: 12px;
}

.icon-smartphone {
  width: 10px;
  height: 16px;
}

.header .active-link,
.header .nav-link:hover,
.header .nav-contact:hover,
.header .nav-link:focus,
.header .nav-contact:focus {
  color: var(--accent-color);
  fill: var(--accent-color);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="uk">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>WebStudio</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modern-normalize/1.1.0/modern-normalize.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body class="studio">
    <header class="header">
      <div class="container flex-container">
        <nav class="flex-container">
          <a class="logo" href="./index.html"><span class="accent">Web</span>Studio</a>
          <ul class="nav-list flex-container">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active-link" href="./index.html">Студія</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="./portfolio.html">Портфоліо</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Контакти</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul class="nav-contacts flex-container">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-contact" href="mailto:info@devstudio.com">
              <svg class="contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 43 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M38.667 0H4C1.795 0 0 1.795 0 4v24c0 2.205 1.795 4 4 4h34.667c2.205 0 4-1.795 4-4V4c0-2.205-1.795-4-4-4zm0 2.667c.181 0 .355.037.512.104L21.334 18.238 3.489 2.771c.151-.065.327-.104.512-.104h34.667zm0 26.666H4A1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2.667 28V5.587l17.792 15.421c.233.203.539.327.875.327s.642-.124.876-.328l-.002.001L40 5.587V28c0 .736-.597 1.333-1.333 1.333z"/>
</svg>
              info@devstudio.com</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-contact" href="tel:+380961111111">
              <svg class="contact-icon icon-smartphone" viewBox="0 0 20 32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M17 0H3C1.346 0 0 1.346 0 3v26c0 1.654 1.346 3 3 3h14c1.654 0 3-1.346 3-3V3c0-1.654-1.346-3-3-3zM3 2h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v21H2V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm14 28H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3h16v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z"/><path d="M4.708 27.478a.889.889 0 0 1 .001 1.319l-.001.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1-1.417 0l.001.001a.889.889 0 0 1-.001-1.319l.001-.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1 1.417 0l-.001-.001z"/>
</svg>+38 096 111 11 11</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

I trying to make central vertical alignment for two anchors with svg icons from svg-sprite. Display flex and align-items center for  doesn't help (not enough). Combination of inline-block and vertical-align middle too.

[Github Link](https://github.com/MaxF1996/goit-markup-hw-04) [Github Pages Link](https://maxf1996.github.io/goit-markup-hw-04/index.html) [Figma](https://www.figma.com/file/14GxHIOZ38pVyN635NXv9i/Web-Studio-(Version-2.1)-(Copy))

[picture of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udpHU.png) [CodePen Code](https://codepen.io/maxf1996/pen/dyeMpap)

Right now in repository you can see display flex and align-items center;

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Look template 4-8 in figma

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a code (inline svg without sprite was used for snippet), use full page watching, because css for adaptive not included. Strange - if i use small literals in contacts - all fine, if numbers or big literals - we have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Flex `align-items` works as expected, but it can't "automagically" adjust icon sizes to get the same visual height.

You could normalize your svg sizes by tweaking the `viewBox` values. This could be achieved even better with `<use>` instances referencing sprite elements.

#### Example 1: viewBox adjustments for same visual heights

```css
.wrap {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.2em;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <svg class="contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 43 45">
    <use href="#icon-envelope" />
  </svg>
  <svg class="contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 20 32">
    <use href="#icon-smartphone" />
  </svg> 
Baseline
</div>


<svg class="sprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <symbol id="icon-envelope" class="contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 43 32">
    <path d="M38.667 0H4C1.795 0 0 1.795 0 4v24c0 2.205 1.795 4 4 4h34.667c2.205 0 4-1.795 4-4V4c0-2.205-1.795-4-4-4zm0 2.667c.181 0 .355.037.512.104L21.334 18.238 3.489 2.771c.151-.065.327-.104.512-.104h34.667zm0 26.666H4A1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2.667 28V5.587l17.792 15.421c.233.203.539.327.875.327s.642-.124.876-.328l-.002.001L40 5.587V28c0 .736-.597 1.333-1.333 1.333z" />
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="icon-smartphone" class="icon contact-icon icon-smartphone" viewBox="0 0 20 32" >
    <path d="M17 0H3C1.346 0 0 1.346 0 3v26c0 1.654 1.346 3 3 3h14c1.654 0 3-1.346 3-3V3c0-1.654-1.346-3-3-3zM3 2h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v21H2V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm14 28H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3h16v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z" />
    <path d="M4.708 27.478a.889.889 0 0 1 .001 1.319l-.001.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1-1.417 0l.001.001a.889.889 0 0 1-.001-1.319l.001-.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1 1.417 0l-.001-.001z" />

  </symbol>
</svg>
```

#### Example 2: `<use>` elements in nav

```css
:root {
  --main-font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  --main-font-size: 14px;
  --main-line-height: 1.71;
  --logo-font-family: Raleway, Roboto, sans-serif;
  --logo-font-size: 26px;
  --main-letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  --main-font-color: #757575;
  --title-font-color: #212121;
  --logo-font-color: #000000;
  --main-light-color: #ffffff;
  --contacts-font-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  --accent-color: #2196f3;
  --main-dark-color: #2f303a;
  --secondary-bg-color: #f5f4fa;
  --header-border-color: #ececec;
}


/* Загальні стилі */

body.studio {
  font-family: var(--main-font-family);
  font-size: var(--main-font-size);
  line-height: var(--main-line-height);
  letter-spacing: var(--main-letter-spacing);
  color: var(--main-font-color);
  background-color: var(--main-light-color);
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

main img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}


/* .container.big-container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding: 0;
} */

.section {
  padding-top: 94px;
  padding-bottom: 94px;
}

.title {
  color: var(--title-font-color);
}

.header .nav-link,
.header .nav-contact,
.footer .address-geo,
.footer .address-contact {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header .nav-list,
.header .nav-contacts,
.footer .address-list,
.benefits-list,
.doing-list,
.team-list,
.works-list,
.works-filters {
  list-style: none;
}

.logo {
  font-family: var(--logo-font-family);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: var(--logo-font-size);
  line-height: 1.174;
  letter-spacing: var(--main-letter-spacing);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accent {
  color: var(--accent-color);
}

.unvisible {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
}


/* Шапка */

.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--header-border-color);
}

.header .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav.flex-container {
  column-gap: 93px;
}

.header .logo {
  color: var(--logo-font-color);
}

.header .nav-list {
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.nav-item {
  line-height: 0;
}

.header .nav-link,
.header .nav-contact {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.17;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}

.header .nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 31px;
  color: var(--title-font-color);
}

.header .nav-contacts {
  margin-left: auto;
  column-gap: 50px;
}

.header .nav-contact {
  color: inherit;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  fill: var(--main-font-color);
}

.svg-icon {
  height: 1.6em;
}

.icon-envelope {}

.icon-smartphone {}

.header .active-link,
.header .nav-link:hover,
.header .nav-contact:hover,
.header .nav-link:focus,
.header .nav-contact:focus {
  color: var(--accent-color);
  fill: var(--accent-color);
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modern-normalize/1.1.0/modern-normalize.min.css" />

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body class="studio">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container flex-container">
      <nav class="flex-container">
        <a class="logo" href="./index.html"><span class="accent">Web</span>Studio</a>
        <ul class="nav-list flex-container">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active-link" href="./index.html">Студія</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="./portfolio.html">Портфоліо</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">Контакти</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <ul class="nav-contacts flex-container">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-contact" href="mailto:info@devstudio.com">
            <svg class="svg-icon contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 43 45">
              <use href="#icon-envelope" />
            </svg> info@devstudio.com
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-contact" href="tel:+380961111111">
            <svg class="svg-icon contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 20 32">
              <use href="#icon-smartphone" />
            </svg>+38 096 111 11 11</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <svg class="sprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" style="display:none">
    <symbol id="icon-envelope" class="contact-icon icon-envelope" viewBox="0 0 43 32">
      <path d="M38.667 0H4C1.795 0 0 1.795 0 4v24c0 2.205 1.795 4 4 4h34.667c2.205 0 4-1.795 4-4V4c0-2.205-1.795-4-4-4zm0 2.667c.181 0 .355.037.512.104L21.334 18.238 3.489 2.771c.151-.065.327-.104.512-.104h34.667zm0 26.666H4A1.333 1.333 0 0 1 2.667 28V5.587l17.792 15.421c.233.203.539.327.875.327s.642-.124.876-.328l-.002.001L40 5.587V28c0 .736-.597 1.333-1.333 1.333z" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon-smartphone" class="icon contact-icon icon-smartphone" viewBox="0 0 20 32">
      <path d="M17 0H3C1.346 0 0 1.346 0 3v26c0 1.654 1.346 3 3 3h14c1.654 0 3-1.346 3-3V3c0-1.654-1.346-3-3-3zM3 2h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v21H2V3a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zm14 28H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1v-3h16v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z" />
      <path d="M4.708 27.478a.889.889 0 0 1 .001 1.319l-.001.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1-1.417 0l.001.001a.889.889 0 0 1-.001-1.319l.001-.001a1.048 1.048 0 0 1 1.417 0l-.001-.001z" />

    </symbol>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Figma layout, you have a line height of 16 pixels, and on the site you have a svg icon height of 16 pixels, and a phone number of 17 pixels (that's why you can't align your element the way you want).
All you have to do is just change the line height of the class:

```
.header .nav-link, .header .nav-contact {
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 1em;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
```

}

Comment: No, doesn't help/

Comment: in my projects I usually use an svg sprite like in the answer above "Example 2: <use> elements in nav", if you're interested, here is an accessible explanation of how to do it:
https://frontips.ru/sozdayom-i-ispolzuem-simvolnyj-svg-sprajt/